# What is the TypeScript definition of a matrix defined with nester Array.fill

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

Any hints on what the correct TypeScript definition for this would be? Basically a 5x5 matrix with empty strings.

```
const arr = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill('', 0), 0)
```

What I tried so far is:

```
const arr: Array<Array<string>> = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill('', 0), 0)
```

but I get **Unsafe assignment of type any[] to a variable of type string[][].**

One hint I have from VSCode (mouse over the Array definition) is this:

```
var Array: ArrayConstructor (arrayLength?: number | undefined) => any[] (+2 overloads)
```

Does this mean that using ***ArrayConstructor*** I need to find a way to define the return value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `string[][]`?

Comment: Or since you know the return value will match the object types of `string[][]` you could write `var arr: string[][] = <string[][]>Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill(''));`

Comment: @JoshuaSmart yes, `string[][]` is basically `Array<Array<string>>`

Comment: @JoshuaSmart this worked `<string[][]>(Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill(' ', 0), 0))`, thanks